# Vertically join two dataframes by rows with common values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataframes:

```
dat1<- data.frame(V1=c("A1","B"),V2=c("A2","B"),V3=c("A3","B"),V4=c("A4","B"),V5=c("A5", "B")) 
dat1

#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
# 2  B  B  B  B  B

dat2<- data.frame(V8=c("A1","C"),V9=c("A3","C"), V10=c("A5", "C"))
dat2

#   V8 V9 V10
# 1 A1 A3  A5
# 2  C  C   C
```

I would like to join these two dataframes according to the values in the first row that they have in common (A1, A3 and A5). Ideally, I would like to achieve a dataframe that looks like this:

```
#   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
# 1 A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
# 2 B   B   B   B   B
# 3 C  <NA> C  <NA> C
```

How can this be done? I would especially appreciate a solution that uses dplyr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try transposing and joining -

```
library(dplyr)

dat1 %>% t %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  left_join(dat2 %>% t %>%as.data.frame(), by = 'V1') %>%
  t %>% as.data.frame(row.names = FALSE) 

#  V1   V2 V3   V4 V5
#1 A1   A2 A3   A4 A5
#2  B    B  B    B  B
#3  C <NA>  C <NA>  C
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
data.table::transpose(setDT(data.table::transpose(dat1))[
     data.table::transpose(dat2), V3 := i.V2, on = .(V1)])
   V1   V2 V3   V4 V5
1: A1   A2 A3   A4 A5
2:  B    B  B    B  B
3:  C <NA>  C <NA>  C
```